# SharedPreferences, string called out not recognizable for listview ifelse

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have done some codes with regards to SharedPreferences, with the extends of saving and loading data with 2 buttons, respectively save and load. both functions work well, but when i kill the application and go back, I press on the load button, it loads out my array saved previously and i load this array on to a listview, but when i click listview, it seemed that the strings in the array don't seem to be able to perform the activity i have.

Anyone has meet on this problem or similar?

```
    final Button a = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save); 
    a.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) { 
            int mode= MODE_PRIVATE;

            // get the sharedPreference of your context.

            SharedPreferences  mySharedPreferences ; mySharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences("shared",MODE_PRIVATE);

            // retrieve an editor to modify the shared preferences

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor= mySharedPreferences.edit();

            /* now store your primitive type values. In this case it is true, 1f and Hello! World  */

            for (String s : global.ItemArray){
            editor.putString("share", s);
            }
            //save the changes that you made

            editor.commit();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Favourites saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show();

        }
    });
    final Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.load); 
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) { 
            global.ItemArray.clear();

            int mode = Activity.MODE_PRIVATE;

            SharedPreferences  mySharedPreferences ; 
            mySharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences("shared", MODE_PRIVATE);

            // Retrieve the saved values.

            String mSstring = null;

            mSstring= mySharedPreferences.getString("share", mSstring);
            /*if (mSstring == "1"){
                global.ItemArray.add("Introduction To BCLS");
            }*/
            global.ItemArray.add(mSstring);
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Favourites loaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show();

            lv1.setAdapter(arrad);
        }





        }
    );
```

Comment: Are you sure you are able to load the right `global.ItemArray` with all the values?

Comment: "but when i click listview, it seemed that the strings in the array dont seem to be able to perform the activity i have."  Can you explain what you mean by this part?

Comment: normally. when i add strings to this global array "global.ItemArray", and add them to a listview,

Comment: i have certain actions when i click on them

Comment: and it works fine, but when i use the shared preferences, to save and load them out again, the strings from the array is not working anymore, as it, it looks the same, but yet it doesn't do the actions i programmed it to do, its just like strings in a normal listview without any actions

Comment: if you guys need my entire code, pls tell me.

Answer (score 0):

Its because you need a unique name for each string you are sharing

try this while adding

```
    for(int i =0; i < global.ItemArray.length; i ++){
        editor.putString("share" + i, global.ItemArray.get(i));
    }
```

and this while removing

```
    for(int i =0; i < global.ItemArray.length; i ++){
        global.ItemArray.add(i, editor.getString("share" + i);
    }
```

these may not be syntactically correct so treat them as psuedo-code please